# GWT environment errors within ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threads

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to write a server-side component of a GWT application which should pull an XML file every 3 minutes and keep a Hashtable up to date after parsing the XML.

After some research, I set up the thread using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

```
stationParser = new TFLStationsParserThread(bikeStations);
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(stationParser, 2, 180, SECONDS);
```

The TFLStationsParserThread has a minimal constructor, and this run() method

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("TFLStationsParserThread run()");
    stationParser.refreshStationData(stations);
}
```

The stationParser eventually gets the data with the following command

```
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
```

Here is my problem: When this `.fetch()` is run from within a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor I get the following error

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:37)
    at couk.mtaylor.bikes.server.TFLStationsParser.refreshStationData(TFLStationsParser.java:66)
    at couk.mtaylor.bikes.server.TFLStationsParserThread.run(TFLStationsParserThread.java:35)
    ...
```

If I comment out the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` scheduler and call `refreshStationData` directly then I get no such issue.

This leads me to believe that the thread is missing some required GWT libraries, but this is beyond my knowledge and I cannot find any solutions online that are helping.

Why would I be getting these GWT error messages from within a scheduled thread but not when I call the method directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm this, but I think this might be GAE's way of telling me this is not how to do threads in GAE. The code works fine if I remove GAE from the buildpath and stop using .fetch().

For now I'm dropping the idea of writing for GAE while I get more used to Java.

Answer (score 0):

[getting strange exception trying to implement asynchronous http in google app engine for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299673/getting-strange-exception-trying-to-implement-asynchronous-http-in-google-app-en)

Are you trying to run it as a Java application and not a web application?

Comment: Is is running as a gwt web application

Comment: Note the library is com.google.apphosting. I would check that you have not accidentally imported the wrong libray for HTTPRequest.

Comment: Hi. If we are talking about the specific class which contains .fetch() then I believe I am importing the correct libraries.

    import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader;
    import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest;
    import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse;