# Sending sms with twilio: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sms, twilio

I'm running this code:

`ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN` = are from my account

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Account account = client.getAccount();

    MessageFactory messageFactory = account.getMessageFactory();
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", ...my number...));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", ...my twilio number..));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Where's Wallace?"));
    Message sms = messageFactory.create(params);

    String a = "1";
}
```

but get this exception when running `messageFactory.create`

I have run:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

any idea how to fix this?

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.waze.beacon.inline.server.services.SmsSenderImp.main(SmsSenderImp.java:33)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
    ... 16 more
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request: Error flushing content in Google App Engine fetch
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.waze.beacon.inline.server.services.SmsSenderImp.main(SmsSenderImp.java:33)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
    ... 16 more
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request: Error flushing content in Google App Engine fetch
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.waze.beacon.inline.server.services.SmsSenderImp.main(SmsSenderImp.java:33)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
    ... 16 more
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request: Error flushing content in Google App Engine fetch
Apr 01, 2016 10:07:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.waze.beacon.inline.server.services.SmsSenderImp.main(SmsSenderImp.java:33)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
    ... 16 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error flushing content in Google App Engine fetch
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:437)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:581)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.waze.beacon.inline.server.services.SmsSenderImp.main(SmsSenderImp.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error flushing content in Google App Engine fetch
    at com.twilio.sdk.AppEngineClientConnection.flush(AppEngineClientConnection.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:410)
    ... 3 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61151', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this question here that seems to be similar: [getting strange exception trying to implement asynchronous http in google app engine for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299673/getting-strange-exception-trying-to-implement-asynchronous-http-in-google-app-en)

According to the accepted answer by @Antony, the issue is that these APIs are not available in the local dev server, but they will be when deployed in Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Megan from Twilio here.

I'm not very familiar with App Engine but your app is looking for a specific implementation of `URLFetchService` and cannot find it.

There are a few [issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/issues/102) regarding the use of [Twilio-Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) with App Engine on GitHub that may be relevant.

Example of expected class:

```
Class.forName("com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest");
```

Let me know if this helps at all.